# jQuery and speed of .replaceWith() vs. .html()

Tags: jquery

I have a simple HTML code:

```
<div class="inner"><h2>Old heading</h2></div>
```

Which one is faster, A) or B)?

A)

```
$( 'div.inner' ).replaceWith( '<div class="inner"><h2>New heading</h2></div>' );
```

B)

```
$( "div.inner" ).html( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
```

Is there even faster ways available?

Comment: I did add the final question to my original opening message to find out if there are even faster ways.

Answer (score 2):

Using `html()` is going to be significantly faster than using the `replaceWith()` function, roughly twice as fast (~57% when ran locally). This can be expected as at it core, it's just a wrapper for setting the `innerHtml` property of an element.

**The Numbers**

- **`replaceWith()`** - averaged 24,767 operations/second
- **`html()`** - averaged 58,446 operations/second

These [tests were run using jsPerf and can be seen here](https://jsperf.com/jquery-perf-tests) and demonstrated below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

B) would be quicker, as it directly invokes `innerHTML`.

A) would go to the parent element and call `replaceChild`.

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/56136897f241db22560b58c3518578ca1453d5c7/src/manipulation.js#L451

Answer (score 0):

Here's a test case I prepared for you

https://jsperf.com/jqueryroller

The results (on my PC) show that html() is about 2x times faster than replaceWith().

You can use jsperf to test similar things in the future and even edit my tests if you need to.